# Running flask with self signed SSL certificate prompts "The connection was reset." from chrome

Tags: flask, pyopenssl

I'm attempting to test OAuth, logins, so I need HTTPS connection. I am using flask, so to achieve this I self-signed a certificate and am using the following function to run flask:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'), port = 5000)
```

Whenever I try to connect to localhost:5000, I get the following error message from chrome:

```
This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset.
```

No indication from flask that any connection was made. (No files were served.) The app works perfectly (besides OAuth) when the ssl_context parameter is not in app.run, but it is served over HTTP. I have checked the option on chrome experimental to allow unsecure certificates on localhost.

I have used the local server over HTTPS one time, and it worked fine - after I rebooted the server, I have not been able to recreate the success. I have attempted switching the port, switching browsers, and switching to a new certificate.

Answer (score 4):

Minutes after posting, I realized HTTPS is not implied, and therefore when accessing localhost:5000, it is paramount that I type https://localhost:5000, with the https included.

I am going to leave this up just in case someone runs into the same issue.